# How can I monitor the current keyboard layout?

Tags: scripts, keyboard, 22.04, keyboard-layout

In the context of the `xmonad` window manager, I want to write a program running in the background and launched at login time that writes to a particular file the current keyboard layout every time it changes.

One solution is to do polling : the process asks every X seconds the system the current layout, for example using `setxkbmap -query`, parses the output, and writes its result to the file.

What am I looking for is a non polling solution, where my process would "register" for "keyboard layout change event" from the system. Is it possible to do that, and if yes, how ?

Comment: Have you tried this c program : https://stackoverflow.com/q/35569562/724406 but suspect it doesn't work for Wayland.